# How to handle image aspect ratio on different resolutions and rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

What's the right and clean way to handle images aspect ratio?

In my app, if I rotate the screen, I lose the aspect ratio and my images appear ugly as hell
- see these images comparing my app and Play Store - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EzKO.jpg

This is how I'm doing:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/stark"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLannister"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/stark"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How should I handle the height? Should I set a fixed value? Or is there any way it automatically keeps the aspect ratio?

The image I'm using is 400x300 pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `ImageViews` instead of buttons - they can be clickable just like buttons. You can set how the images scale using the `scaleType` attribute.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

For example, with CENTER_INSIDE:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

So, something like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnStark"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/stark"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

A Lannister always pays his debts.

Comment: Thanks. The ImageView really solved the aspect ratio problem.
Another question: Is it the best practice to set a fixed value for android:layout_height?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ImageButton` instead of a simple `Button` and try different [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) modes to select what fits you better.